# Unable to get/read cookies from the server using electron application

Tags: javascript, session, electron, session-cookies, axios

I am trying to create an electron application where user logs in from the application and after successful authentication server sends some cookies in form of response headers.

When I send the user details I get the something like this in the response
`This browser is not supported`.

**My question**:

1. How to fix this `browser not supported issue` is there any headers that I should append to fake it that I am using latest version of chrome or something similar ?
2. After this how am I supposed to save the cookie in the application and use it for the later `GET` / `POST` requests i.e. maintain my session with the server.

Here is the code I am using:

```
var axios = require('axios')
axios
  .post('http://mywebsiteurl', {
    data: {
      username: 'username',
      password: 'password'
    },
    withCredentials: true
  })
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response)
  })
```

If someone can help me in this issue or is there any other library which handles session smoothly?? I am really new to electron
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For #2, you have to set the following on the server:

1. Access-Control-Allow-Origin to the domain name where the request is coming from. For example, I have mine set http://localhost:8080 since I'm testing locally.
2. Access-Control-Allow-Credentials to true.